# Characters in GAP

Tags: representation-theory, gap

Having a character of a representation $V$ over a finite group in characteristic zero, how to obtain the characters of symmetric or exterior powers of $V$ in GAP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are searching for he commands `SymmetricParts(tbl,characterlist,exponent)`, respectively `AntiSymmetricParts` for exterior powers. See the manual
https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap72.html#X85CE68CA87CA383A

for more details.
Your character table needs to know suitable power maps.